# Whenever gem - runner failing for one Model? Illegal name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever, runner

I have a model called Task.

```
rails runner -e development "Task.myClassMethod"
```

Results in this:

```
Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run.
Run 'bin/rails runner -h' for help.
undefined method `myClassMethod' for Thor::Command:Class
```

This works in any of my other models.  I tried clearing out my Task model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    def self.myClassMethod
        pp 'Hello'
    end
end
```

I've also tried running rails app:update:bin per this thread: https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/663

But still getting the same errors.  Is this a naming conflict?

Comment: what is `andrew` method?

Comment: Sorry - wrong error message, I've updated the question.

Comment: Why are you referring to `whenever` gem when you try to do a `rails runner` command? What is the link? The error refers to `Thor::Command::Class` is that something you are using or referring to in your `Task` (deriving from?)

Comment: I get the same error when using whenever or using the runner command in the console. Same method works fine in both using any other model in the app.